# When I go back to a Fragment the observer is immediately called

Tags: android, kotlin, observers

I have an observer than when it's called changes fragments.

The problem is when i go back the observer is called immediately and my app crashes with a

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination
>   com.superapps.ricardo.tablepro:id/action_searchFragment_to_yourGameList2
>   is unknown to this NavController.

I don't understand why it is being called.

this is the only method that changes the list

```
override fun onSuccess(gamePair: Pair<Int, List<BggGame>>) {
        CoroutineScope(Main).launch{
            //goToList(gamePair.second, binding.input.text.toString())
            viewModel.setGameList(gamePair.second)
        }
    }
```

and this is the viewmodel creation and change fragment code

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.gameList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            goToList(it, binding.input.text.toString())
        })
    }


    private fun goToList(games: List<BggGame>, user: String) {
        val action = SearchFragmentDirections.actionSearchFragmentToYourGameList2(user)
        val gameList = GameList()
        gameList.gameList = games
        action.gameList = gameList

        try {
            Navigation.findNavController(view!!).navigate(action)
            viewModel.gameList.removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)
        } catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e("a0,","a..", e)
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss()

    }
```

Comment: Please share your viewModel codes!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LiveData` keeps the last value that have been set. When calling `observe()` on a `LivaData`, if the `LiveData` has a value, the observer is instantly called with the value previously set.

If you want to use `LiveData` for "events" like your usecase, your live data should expose an `Event` object that can be consumed only once.

Here is an example of a good [implementation](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) of such an `Event` class.

From the article :

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

Usage in ViewModel :

```
val gameList = MutableLiveData<Event<List<BggGame>>()
fun setGameList(gameList: List<BggGame>) {
    gameList.value = Event(gameList)
}
```

Usage in view :

```
viewModel.gameList.observe(this, Observer {
    it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { // Only proceed if the event has never been handled
        goToList(it, binding.input.text.toString())
    }
})
```

Comment: You forgot the example  xD

Comment: Indeed, I updated the post with a link to a very good explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your `viewModel` use `SingleLiveEvent` instead of `MutableLiveData` or `LiveData`.

This is `SingleLiveEvent` class , you can use it in `util` package :

```
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.MainThread;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class SingleLiveEvent<T> extends MutableLiveData<T> {

    private static final String TAG = "SingleLiveEvent";

    private final AtomicBoolean mPending = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Override
    public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) {

        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.");
        }

        // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
        super.observe(owner, new Observer<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable T t) {
                if (mPending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                    observer.onChanged(t);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @MainThread
    public void setValue(@Nullable T t) {
        mPending.set(true);
        super.setValue(t);
    }
}
```